# Authenticated referrals option disappeared

Tags: authentication, facebook-apps

I just created my second app, and I want to enable Authenticated Referrals as I made on my first app. But the "Authenticated Referrals" option has disappeared in Settings > Permissions, however that option is still in the Facebook app's documentation : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC6A0.jpg

Can you help me to retrieve this option ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Authenticated Referrals are removed for new applications as described in this blog post

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/

> Authenticated referrals create an inconsistent experience for people by asking them to give permissions in order to access content with little context. You must migrate to use a standard Auth Dialog experience.

Comment: Hm, ok... not very practical... Thank you !

Comment: @MorganTouvereyQuilling that's something you will have to take up with Facebook, it is what it is. They have decided the experience doesn't help so they are removing it. It's less about practicality and more about how the company views the experience apps share with users.